# Angular: Access html element by Controller without jQuery usage

Tags: angularjs

I want to access an `html` element in my Controller. The issue with this element is that it is created automatically by an external library on the DOM. That means that I cannot import any directive inside my html.

So the question is:
Is there any way to access the aforementioned element without jQuery usage?

Here is an example:

```
<span class='element1'>Element 1</span>
```

What I would like to avoid inside the Controller is this:

```
$('element1').doSomething();
```

Comment: You can use `angular.element()` to access elements .

Answer (score 1):

[angular element docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

You can use either the angular element subset of jquery or the full jquery library